# Make slurm to run script using all cpu's in the cluster

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, cluster-computing, slurm

I'm completly new to slurm and debian.
I have a cluster with 27 nodes with debian each has a processor with 24 cores. On my main node runing slurmctld i have a script which takes as much resources as it can. The question is, can I run it with all the cpu's in a cluster? if so then how. I know how to run a script that uses stress package and uses all cpus on 2 nodes :

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#SBATCH --job-name=test
#
#SBATCH --nodes=2
#SBATCH --ntasks=48
#SBATCH --time=00:00:20

srun sudo stress --cpu 48 --timeout 20
```

but i have to install the stress package on every I'm using.